# Perl regex first word

Tags: regex, perl

I am very new to regex in perl and I have the following line:

```
MD5ajdhe728ndsdhsds83ndsds /some/path/
```

and I just want to get the MD5 value (the number/letter combination after "MD5"). How do I do that? I have kind of troubles fetching the first word.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $line = q{MD5ajdhe728ndsdhsds83ndsds /some/path/};
$line =~ /^MD5([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/;
print $1;
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/BzNyvQ)